# Flutter/web: render html with two adjacent divs

Tags: html, css, flutter, flutter-web

I have a flutter/web application and I want to create a HTML document that

- I can render in my flutter app
- I can (optionally) send it by e-mail

I want to have two adjacent divs (see image): this image is taken from a webbrowser rendering the HTML below.  The HTML contains three options to position the divs (using float, using position and using tables).

[image]

However, I fail to display this a Flutter widget. `webview_flutter` does not support Web (only Android and iOS), `flutter_widget_from_html_core` seems to have problems with this HTML (simple HTML works fine), ...

Are there other options to embed an HTML fragment in the Flutter widget tree? A modified HTML (with the same result) that can be rendered in eg `flutter_widget_from_html_core` is also fine!

```
<div id="option-float" style="height: 64px;">
    <div style="background: #FF0000; height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 16px; float: left; ">
        <div style="color: #FDA720;">
            <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/785/PNG/512/stopwatch_icon-icons.com_64805.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin: 16px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background: #00FF00; height: 64px; float: left; margin-left: 16px; display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; ">
            <span style="font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: bold;">Text1</span> <br>
            <span style="font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: bold; color: #FDA720;">Text2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div id="option-position" style="height: 64px;">
    <div style="background: #FF0000; height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 16px; ">
        <div style="color: #FDA720;">
            <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/785/PNG/512/stopwatch_icon-icons.com_64805.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin: 16px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background: #00FF00; height: 64px; margin-left: 16px; display: table; position: relative; left: 64px; top: -64px; ">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; ">
            <span style="font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: bold;">Text1</span> <br>
            <span style="font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: bold; color: #FDA720;">Text2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table id="option-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="background: #FF0000; height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 16px; ">
            <div style="color: #FDA720;">
                <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/785/PNG/512/stopwatch_icon-icons.com_64805.png" width="32" height="32" style="margin: 16px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="background: #00FF00; height: 64px; margin-left: 16px; display: table;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; ">
                <span style="font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: bold;">Text1</span> <br>
                <span style="font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: bold; color: #FDA720;">Text2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Hi Marc, is this issue resolved for you? I'm struggling a bit while using flutter_html_all package. Here is the issue I'm facing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74259662/elements-are-not-coming-in-single-line-display-flex-not-working-in-flutter-ht

Some help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not: I've been playing with both flutter_widget_from_html and flutter_html, with tables and divs, with a lot of combinations of float & display, with or without inlining the CSS but found nothing that seemed to work for all cases.  I was surprised that there was no full fledged integration standard available in flutter.